# Turn on light/torch with front camera

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I know how to turn on/off the flash light from the back camera. I know how to switch front/back camera. But I don't know how to turn on/off the flash light independently from the active camera.

What I mean: if the active camera is the front one, when I turn on the flash light, it freezes. And when I turn it off, it unfreezes.

My code so far:

```
var back_cam:AVCaptureDevice?
for device in devices{
    if (device as AnyObject).hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) && (device as AnyObject).position == .back{
        back_cam=device as? AVCaptureDevice
    }
}

guard let cam=back_cam else {
    print("no back cam?")
    return
}

if cam.hasTorch{
    do{
        try cam.lockForConfiguration()
            if cam.torchMode == .on{
                cam.torchMode = .off
            }else{
                do{
                    try cam.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1)
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            cam.unlockForConfiguration()
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

In case I'm not clear, I'd like to keep the light on, regardless of wether the active camera is the back one or the front one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check torch mode is supported for the device or not before you turn on/off.

As per Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1386035-torchmode) for

```
var torchMode: AVCaptureTorchMode { get set }
```

> Before setting the value of this property, call the
>   isTorchModeSupported(_:) method to make sure the device supports the
>   desired mode. Setting the device to an unsupported torch mode results
>   in the raising of an exception.

Also when you switch to front camera, the default behaviour is torch mode off. Compare it with default camera app from iPhone/iPad.

Comment: "the default behaviour is torch mode off": but I am precisely trying NOT to get the default behaviour, I want the light to be on, regardless of wether the active camera is the back one or the front one.

Comment: when you change to the front camera, isTorchModeSupported is returning false. which means we can't override the default behaviour in this case

Comment: Yes I guess it's not possible... Thanks anyway.